# How can I properly overload static methods in TypeORM's BaseEntity to avoid TypeScript errors?

Tags: typeorm

How can I overload static methods from TypeORM BaseEntity? Everything I tried generates typescript error. I used to do this at v0.2, but can't in v0.3

```
class MyTweakedBaseEntity extends BaseEntity {
 static find<T extends BaseEntity>(this: (new () => T) & typeof BaseEntity, options?: FindManyOptions<T>): Promise<T[]> {
    return super.find<T>(options);
  }
}
```

Results in

```
Class static side 'typeof MyTweakedBaseEntity' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof BaseEntity'.
  The types returned by 'find(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'Promise<BaseEntity[]>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<T[]>'.
      Type 'BaseEntity[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
        Type 'BaseEntity' is not assignable to type 'T'.
          'BaseEntity' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'BaseEntity'.ts(2417)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a type assertion (`as`) to inform the TypeScript compiler that the returned value from `super.find<T>(options)` is of type `T[]`:

```
class MyTweakedBaseEntity extends BaseEntity {
  static find<T extends BaseEntity>(this: (new () => T) & typeof BaseEntity, options?: FindManyOptions<T>): Promise<T[]> {
    return super.find<T>(options) as Promise<T[]>; // <-- there
  }
}
```

By using as `Promise<T[]>`, you're asserting that the return value of `super.find<T>(options)` is of type `T[]`. This informs the TypeScript compiler that the returned value is compatible with the `Promise<T[]>` type expected by the overridden find method.